# Proving that a set in which any sequence having exactly one accumulation point converges is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I found the following question about compactness:

> A set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has the following property:
>   if a sequence of $S$ has exactly one accumulation point in $S$, then it converges in $S$. Prove that $S$ is compact.

We know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact sets correspond to closed and bounded sets.

(1) I am trying to prove that $S$ is closed. The condition in the question says if a sequence of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$ then it converges in $S$. I think instead the condition should be if a sequence of $S$ has an accumulation point( in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not necessarily in $S$ )then it converges in $S$.

Am I correct?

(2) How to prove that $S$ is bounded?

P.S. I have made an edit (there is exactly one accumulation point).

Source of the question: [Question 1](https://math.indiana.edu/documents/tier-1-exams/analysis/2017-01-analysis-t1.pdf) of this problem set.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right.

Comment: The property isn't true. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ : no sequence in $\Bbb{Z}$ has an accumulation point and therefore the condition is vacuously satisfied, but obviously $\Bbb{Z}$ isn't compact.

Comment: @Max in $\mathbb Z$, eventually constant sequences indeed have accumulation points.

Comment: @OpenBall eventually constant sequence have accumulation points in $\mathbb{Z}$ and they converge in $\mathbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is still not compact.

Comment: @SahibaArora well, I'm trying to point out to Max that he might have meant something else.

Comment: @Openball : in my definition, an accumulation point needs to be different from the points that are accumulating. But nonetheless, if eventually constant sequences have accumulation points, then any set $S$ with at least two elements doesn't satisfy the hypothesis, so the claim is vacuously true (a set of size $1$ or $0$ is obviously compact)

Answer (score 1):

With the edit, the question makes more sense now.

Now rather than proving $S$ is closed and bounded, you could try proving an equivalent characterization: any sequence has a converging subsequence (it is equivalent in a finite dimensional normed vector space, and equivalent to the "real" definition of compactness in any metric space). I think it would be easier.

I will assume $S\neq \emptyset$ (the case $S=\emptyset$ being trivial).

Assume $(s_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ with no converging subsequence in $S$. In particular it has no accumulation point.

Let $x\in S$ be any point and let $x_{2n} = x$, $x_{2n+1} = s_n$. Since $(s_n)$ has no accumulation point, it follows that $x$ is the only accumulation point of $(x_n)$.

According to the hypothesis, $(x_n)$ converges, which in particular implies that $(s_n)$ converges (as it is a subsequence), which contradicts the assumption that $(s_n)$ had no converging subsequence.

Therefore, $(s_n)$ has a converging subsequence. Such a subsequence has exactly one accumulation point, and it takes values in $S$, therefore, again according to the hypothesis, it converges in $S$.

$(s_n)$ being arbitrary, we proved: any sequence with values in $S$ has a converging subsequence in $S$.

Thus, $S$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that for a metric space, compactness and sequentially compactness are equivalent.

Let $(a_{n})$ be an arbitrary sequence of real numbers in $S$. Then clearly by the hypothesis $(a_{n})$ has an accumulation point in $S$ say $a$.

Then we will construct a convergent subsequence of $(a_{n})$ converging to $a$.

$\because a$ is an accumulation point every neighborhood of $a$ has infinitely many points of $(a_{n})$.

$\therefore B(a,1)$ contains $a_{n_{1}}$.

Further, $B(a,1/2)$ contains infinitely elements of $(a_{n})$. Therefore $\exists \ a_{n_{2}}\in B(a,1/2)$ such that $n_{1}<n_{2}$.
Similarly, $B(a,1/k)$ contains infinitely elements of $(a_{n})$. Therefore $\exists \ a_{n_{k}}\in B(a,1/k)$ such that $n_{k-1}<n_{k}$

Therefore,$\exists$ a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ of $(a_{n})$ converging to $a$.
Hence, every sequence of set $S$ has a convergent subsequence.